# Как проверить была ли нажата любая клавиша на клавиатуре?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Задача состоит в том, что бы в цикле проверить, была ли нажата во время выполнения цикла какая либо клавиша на клавиатуре, и если была нажата - начать цикл заново.

Знаю `_getch();` - Не работает как мне нужно, так как останавливает программу в ожидании нажатия.

Еще знаю `_kbhit();` - Вроде работает как нужно, но если нажать клавишу, то при последующих итерациях цикла `_kbhit();` все равно выдает ненулевое число, даже если я ничего больше не нажму.

Comment: А считать нажатое не годится? `while(_kbhit()) _getch();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объедините их :)

Например, вот цикл, работающий, пока не нажмете `Esc`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0;;++i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            int c = _getch();
            if (c == 0x1B) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот (если я правильно понял) примерно то, что вы хотите:

```
for(int i = 0;;++i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    if(_kbhit())
    {
        while(_kbhit()) _getch();
    }
    else
    {
        _getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы меня не поняли. Или я не понял.
Напишу более предметно.
Идет do {} while()
и в нем мне нужно реализовать проверку того, что я не нажал какую нибудь клавишу на клавиатуре. Тоесть это проверка не должна останавливать выполнение цикла, на самом деле этот цикл - защита от "чит - метода", который можно использовать в программе "Тест реакции". Этот цикл находится на на этапе, где пользователю говорят "Ждите", сейчас(через радномное время) вам выскочит сообщение "Нажмите кнопку!"

Comment: *"Задача состоит в том, что бы в цикле проверить, была ли нажата во время выполнения цикла какая либо клавиша на клавиатуре, и если была нажата - начать цикл заново."* Второй цикл так и делает. Была нажата - цикл продолжается. Не была - ждет нажатия.

Comment: Правил комментарий. Это сделано для того, что бы пользователь не нажимал постоянно кнопку, что бы получить хороший результат

Comment: Ни хрена не понял, словом, разбирайтесь сами. Проверка - kbhit(), если она была нажата - в буфер пошел символ. Как сбросить буфер - я написал. Если вам этого недостаточно, то это уже не ко мне...

Comment: Возможно вы мне помогли! (я начинающий программист)
Скажите конкретно, как отчистить буфер на начале итерации цикла?

Comment: `while(_kbhit()) _getch();`