# Есть ли функция, для замера времени нажатия клавиши?

Tags: c

Подскажите, есть ли функция в Си для замера времени, сколько клавиша была в положении down, а так же какая-либо реализация замера времени между нажатием двух клавиш? Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Есть событие "клавиша нажата" и есть событие "клавиша отпущена". Записывайте время нажатия, время отпускания - по событию, ну и осталось вычесть. Примерно так делают в играх.

Comment: Как вариант, зная что есть автоповтор, можно посчитать сколько времени была посылка одного и того же символа, это решение будет кросплатформенно, но время будет довольно "грубо". Кратно размеру задержки автоповтора. Пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5 допилить время.

Comment: Ещё ссылки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415921/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8

Comment: Укажите ОS и укажите режим консоли, или оконный режим. Вариантов реализации минимум 4. Linux-console Linux-окно, Win-Console Win-окно, консоль-кроссплатформа-грубо, qt-решение. Выберите что-то одно. Если всё сразу - очень обширный ответ.

Comment: @nick_n_a, интересует linux(Ubuntu). Что касается выбора между графическим интерфейсом и консолью, то тут смотря где получиться и где легче реализация

Comment: Я в линкус не силен, используя первую ссылку `_kbhit()` и `_getch()` и засекая время можно получить результат, но весьма неточный.

Comment: Поставьте себе `evbug` модуль ядра (в основной поставке) и радуйтесь. А вообще в Linux надо подписываться на события ядра от системы ввода.

Comment: @nick_n_a, для kbhit() необходима библиотека `conio.h`, но как я понимаю, она уже устаревшая и используется сейчас `ncurses.h`, поправь, если я ошибаюсь. Но проблема в том, что при компиляции не видит `kbhit()`. В чем может быть проблема? `undefined reference to kbhit`